# JSP To PDF Converter By jsPDF

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jspdf

I am trying to convert my jsp page output into PDF. For this, I am trying `jsPDF` API. I did some R&D and wrote the code for the same. There is a PDF getting open but it is blank.
Need some help.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsPDF/examples/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsPDF/jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsPDF/plugins/addimage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsPDF/plugins/cell.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsPDF/plugins/from_html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsPDF/plugins/javascript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsPDF/plugins/split_text_to_size.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsPDF/plugins/standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>

<body id="target">

<div>
    <button id="downloadFile" value="Download PDF" type="button">Download PDF</button>

</body>

    var specialElementHandlers = {
                '#editor': function (element,renderer) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
    
        $('#downloadFile').click(function () {
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            var source = $('#target').html();
            var specialElementHandlers = {
                '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            doc.fromHTML(source, 0.5, 0.5, {
                'width': 75,'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            });
            doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
            doc.save('E:/Test.pdf');
        });
```

For `doc.save('E:/Test.pdf');`, there is an alert says that:

> "Error in function jsPDF/output: saveAs is not defined"

Tell me that what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified my script as below; then it's working fine. But Still not found for doc.save();

```
$('#downloadFile').click(function () {
    var specialElementHandlers = 
        function (element,renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.fromHTML($('#target').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.output('dataurlnewwindow'); 
});
```